# spark submit failed with spark streaming workdcount python code

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I just copied the spark streaming wodcount python code, and use spark-submit to run the wordcount python code in Spark cluster, but it shows the following errors:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
```

I did build the jar spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. And I used the following script to submit:
bin/spark-submit /data/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/wordcount.py --master spark://192.168.100.6:7077 --jars /data/spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4/kafka-assembly/target/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_*.jar.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I just realized you have included the --jars after the script. **The jar files will not be included unless the jars are specified before the script name.**  So use spark-submit --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.3.1.jar Script.py instead of spark-submit Script.py --jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.3.1.jar.

Answer (score 1):

I had to reference a number of jars in my command to get this to work, Maybe try reference the jars explicitly, it might not be picking it up correctly from the jar you built.

```
                /opt/spark/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --jars /root/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.3.1.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/kafka/libs/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.2.2.4.2-2.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/kafka/libs/zkclient-0.3.jar,/root/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar  kafka_wordcount.py kafkaAddress:2181 topicName
```

Actually It looks like its not picking up this jar : kafka_2.10-0.8.1.2.2.4.2-2.jar