# Integrating Apache Kafka with Apache Spark Streaming using Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to integrate Apache Kafka with Apache spark streaming using Python (I am new to all these).

For this I have done the following steps

1. Started Zookeeper
2. Started Apache Kafka
3. Added topic in Apache Kafka
4. Managed to list available topics using this command

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

5. I have taken the Kafka word count code from here

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py

and the code is

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: kafka_wordcount.py <zk> <topic>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

6. I executed the code using the command

> ./spark-submit /root/girish/python/kafkawordcount.py localhost:2181

and I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/girish/python/kafkawordcount.py", line 28, in <module>
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
  File "/root/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 72, in createStream
    raise e
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

7. I have updated the execution code using the answer from this question

[spark submit failed with spark streaming workdcount python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485175/spark-submit-failed-with-spark-streaming-workdcount-python-code)

to

```
 ./spark-submit --jars /root/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/lib/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.3.1.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/kafka/libs/kafka_2.10-0.8.1.2.2.0.0-2041.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/kafka/libs/zkclient-0.3.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/kafka/libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar  /root/girish/python/kafkawordcount.py localhost:2181 <topic name>
```

Now I am getting this error

```
File "/root/girish/python/kafkawordcount.py", line 28, in <module>
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
  File "/root/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/pyspark/streaming/kafka.py", line 67, in createStream
    jstream = helper.createStream(ssc._jssc, kafkaParams, topics, jlevel)
  File "/root/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 529, in __call__
  File "/root/spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 265, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

PS:  I am using Apache Spark 1.2

Comment: What about second parameter (topic name) for ./spark-submit /root/girish/python/kafkawordcount.py localhost:2181 ??

Comment: not sure.  Problem solved by using Spark 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using Apache Spark 1.3 which has better support for Python than version 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue, fixed by adding the kafka-assembly package

```
bin/spark-submit  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.1 ~/py/sparkjob.py
```

Use according to your spark and kafka versions.